# Getting large drive structure information in DOS 7.x

Tags: c++, assembly, dos

I wrote a directory information utility and (because I, and the people I wrote this for collect & use vintage hardware,) made it compatible with DOS and Windows 9x as well as Windows XP/Vista/7/8 64-bit (because we also use those.) The problem I ran into was with Windows 9x and FAT32 drives.  I managed to get it to work as long as Windows 9x was actually loaded, but if I boot to command prompt only, or restart in MS-DOS mode I lose access to the Windows API that allowed me to get the large drive data and it defaulted back to the DOS routine I have.  These are limited to the 2GB limit routines.  Examining how the DOS 7.x programs (chkdsk mainly,) handle this (as they have no problem reporting the correct drive sizes,) it seems they use DOS interrupts (primarily INT 21h,) to do this.  Thinking, no problem, I'll do a quick version check, and if it's DOS 7 or higher I'll just run a quick assembly routing to get the drive structure and calculate the total & free space that way.  Only, the routine (though it doesn't return an error,) doesn't fill my buffer with anything.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>

void main(void) {
    unsigned short hes,hdi,sectors,bytes;
    unsigned long tclusters,fclusters;
    unsigned char far *drivedata;
    char test = '\0';
    char display[17] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int count;

    drivedata = new unsigned char [63];

    for (count = 0; count < 63; count++) drivedata[count] = '\0';

    drivedata[0] = '\x3d';
    drivedata[1] = '\x00';

    hes = FP_SEG(drivedata);
    hdi = FP_OFF(drivedata);

asm {
        push ax
        push es
        push di
        push ds
        push dx
        push cx
        mov ax,0x440d
        mov bx,0x0003
        mov cx,0x484a
        int 21h
        jnc _GOOD
        mov ax,0x7302
        mov es,[hes]
        mov di,[hdi]
        mov dx,0x0003
        mov cx,0x003f
        int 21h
        jnc _GOOD
    }
    test = '\1';
_GOOD:
    asm {
        mov ax,0x440d
        mov bl,0x03
        mov cx,0x486a
        int 21h
        pop cx
        pop dx
        pop ds
        pop di
        pop es
        pop ax
    }

    if (test == '\1') {
        printf("There was an error.\r\n");
        return;
    }



    tclusters = (unsigned long) drivedata[48];
    tclusters = (tclusters * 256) + (unsigned long)drivedata[47];
    tclusters = (tclusters * 256) + (unsigned long)drivedata[46];
    tclusters = (tclusters * 256) + (unsigned long)drivedata[45];
    ++tclusters;

    fclusters = (unsigned long)drivedata[36];
    fclusters = (fclusters * 256) + (unsigned long)drivedata[35];
    fclusters = (fclusters * 256) + (unsigned long)drivedata[34];
    fclusters = (fclusters * 257) + (unsigned long)drivedata[33];

    bytes = (unsigned int)drivedata[5];
    bytes = (bytes * 256) + (unsigned int)drivedata[4];

    sectors = (unsigned long)drivedata[6];
    ++sectors;

    printf("Drive C has:\r\n");
    printf("   Total Clusters: %u\r\n",tclusters);
    printf("    Free Clusters: %u\r\n",fclusters);
    printf("          Sectors: %u\r\n",sectors);
    printf("            Bytes: %u\r\n",bytes);

    printf("\r\n");
    printf("   |  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F\r\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for (count = 0; count < 63; count++) {
        if ((count % 16) == 0) printf("\r\n %c | ",display[(count / 16)]);
        printf("%03u ",drivedata[count]);
    }
    printf("\r\n");

    return;
}
```

That last bit was me trying to figure out what was going wrong.  I was getting strange results, and couldn't figure out a pattern.  Originally, I wasn't worried about clearing the buffer as the INT call should have been filling it with it's own values (except the first 2 bytes, which is supposed to be filled with the EDB data buffer size.) After getting so many apparently random results, I added in the loop at the beginning to fill the buffer with zeroes, then add in the buffer size.  The results stopped being random at that point, they were invariably all zeroes, meaning the INT call isn't filling the buffer.  With a variety of tests, I've confirmed that hes & hdi are correctly being assigned the segment and offset of the buffer address.  I've also tried es & di to the pointer address instead of the buffer address.  I didn't think it would work as everything I read said to set it to the address and not to a pointer, but I was trying everything I could think of.  In all cases, the buffer isn't getting filled with anything.

As you can probably tell, this is just a test program I'm writing to figure out the exact procedure before adding it to my main program (which works just fine except for this one issue.)  The FP_ lines are just macros that could be stated as (unsigned long)(x & 0xffff0000) >> 16 for the segment and (unsigned long)(x & 0x0000ffff) for the offset.  Normally you would pass the pointer (&drivedata,) but drivedata is already a pointer.

The actual output:

```
Drive C has:
   Total Clusters: 1
    Free Clusters: 0
          Sectors: 1
            Bytes: 0

   |  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 | 061 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 
 1 | 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 
 2 | 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 
 3 | 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
```

So, what am I missing?  Like chkdsk, I'm locking the drive before and unlocking it after the call (though I'm not sure of the necessity.)  How can I get this to work right?  Alternately, is there a better way of getting the drive structure (clusters, sectors per cluster, bytes per sector,) than using INT 21h?  Everything I find in searches only point me to Windows API functions, which the user won't have access to, if they do a boot to command prompt etc...

Comment: Am I reading your code wrong?  It looks like if you succeed in locking the drive, you skip over the code to read the data.  Failing that, maybe 1) Setting SI to 0xF1A6.  2) Setting dl to 0x80. 3) Using a bigger buffer (256?).

Comment: Actually, you are not :/  I missed that....  Recompiling now... Back in a sec.

Comment: ***sigh*** Yep, I was skipping my code on success, instead of skipping on failure.  Changed the jnc opcode to jc, and added in a new label (to change the good/bad flag appropriately.)  My bad.  Well, I'm now getting data, though the numbers seem off.  Going to do some more testing now :)  Thanks

Comment: Well, I'm actually getting correct numbers for the most part.  If I use 7303 instead of 7302, all the byte values are correct.  If I use 7302, all the byte values "except" for free clusters are correct. (free clusters come back FF FF FF FF.)  What I'm facing now is that, for some reason I cannot figure out, the math to convert to unsigned long isn't working.  5E F5 1F 00 (l-h becomes 0x001FF55E) which is completely correct on the test drive, becomes 0x0000F65E.  I don't see anything wrong with my math, does anyone else?

Comment: OK, another silly error on my part.  Was using %u specifyer in the printf command without adding the 'l' for long :(  argh... Problem solved, sorry about the bother.  I would prefer not to use the 7303 routine as it is reported to have problems with CD-ROMs.  Going to have to look into that.  Would hate to end up having to write yet another routine :(

Answer (score 1):

Wow, using DOS, that's old-school! Not as old-school as using punch cards, but still...

Apparently, [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) has [FAT 32 support](http://fdlfn.sourceforge.net/). You might try to install it on those machines that don't even have Windows 95 installed.

Comment: People that build vintage systems tend to stick with the OS that was in use at the time.  My little program works on DOS 3+ (really that's as far back as I was wiling to install & test, it may go back further.)  It also works on modern systems (my Windows 7 64-bit for example.)  The only hiccup, is DOS 7 (Windows 9x booted to command prompt.)  That's what I'm trying to get working now, DOS 7.  Just a FYI, I was really glad when they invented the keyboard, punch cards were a real PITA.

Comment: Wow, you should *definitely* check this on CP/M!

Answer (score 1):

For your vintage hobby you should equip yourself with the `LBA` and `FAT32` specifications, [Wikipedia: File Allocation Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) seems to have good links.

One thing you may find out is that those legacy systems (and software written for them) could not handle large disks (disk size > 2^<sup>(32-1)</sup>) gracefully.

Other material I think would be also very important:

- Ralf Brown's Interrupt List - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralf_Brown's_Interrupt_List
- Flambeaux Software's TECH Help! - http://www.danielsays.com/ss-gallery-dos-tech-help-60.html
- Peter Norton's Norton Guides - http://www.whitetown.com/misc/ng/asm/
- Bochs x86 Emulator's BIOS source code - http://bochs.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/lxr/source/bios/

The "better way" that should work for you in all cases would be to use BIOS calls to find out all the basics and then replicate algorithms for calculating the sizes etc. in your own code. In the old DOS days there was no easily reusable API available for non-Microsoft programs. Programs that needed to do advanced things had to know how to do it bare-bone by themselves..

Comment: I'm using BIOS calls now, that is where I ran into the problem :(  I have read up on LBA and FAT32.  I did all that when I was first writing the little utility.  As you can see above, it turns out my problems were all of my own creation.  I'm sorry, I'm not a professional programmer, just an amateur.  I've got it mostly fixed now.  A minor bug to trace down (in the actual utility code,) and a workaround for CD-ROMs and I should be finished.